# How can I show the same HTML 5 Video twice on a website without loading it twice?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I currently have 2 video elements on my html-page.
Both embed exactly the same `.mp4` video from the same URL.

Is there any way to tell the browser to duplicate the rendered video from the first video element instead of letting the browser download both videos?

You can cleary see that the two videos are loaded seperated as they have a different buffering time before playback sometimes and the videos dont play synchronized everytime.

My Code:

```
<video autoplay id="previewVideo" data-videoid="JYpUXXD4xgc">
    <source src="video.php?videoid=JYpUXXD4xgc" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

<video autoplay id="bigVideo"     data-videoid="JYpUXXD4xgc">
    <source src="video.php?videoid=JYpUXXD4xgc" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: You can definitely load a video in JS once and then call it as many times as you want throughout your page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done in some very easy steps via Javascript and the Canvas Element:

**HTML:**

```html
<video autoplay id="previewVideo" data-videoid="JYpUXXD4xgc">
    <source src="video.php?videoid=JYpUXXD4xgc" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>    
<canvas id="bigVideo"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var v = document.getElementById('previewVideo');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('bigVideo');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth);
  var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight);
  canvas.width = cw;
  canvas.height = ch;
  v.addEventListener('play', function() {
    updateBigVideo(this, context, cw, ch);
  }, false);
}, false);


function updateBigVideo(v, c, w, h) {
  if (v.paused || v.ended) return false;
  c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);
  setTimeout(updateBigVideo, 20, v, c, w, h);
}
```

The canvas fetches the image of the video and displays it again on the BigVideo.
The `updateBigVideo()` function is called every 20ms, resulting in a framerate of about 50 FPS.

[Read more](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic)

Comment: Really works like a charm, don't see s single stutter :)

Comment: This may work, but the processing overhead of this is really high. The correct answer should probably be Noble Mushtak's. That's the one that worked for me. Also, this approach won't work if the video comes from another domain and the domain isn't CORS enabled.

Comment: Could this method work if the video source was an iframe element? Eg, if the previewVideo was a playing YouTube embed?

Answer (score 9):

First, make the `<video>` element using JavaScript and then put it in the places you want.

```
var video1 = document.createElement("video");
video1["data-videoid"] = "JYpUXXD4xgc";
var sourceElem = document.createElement("source");
sourceElem.src = "video.php?videoid=JYpUXXD4xgc";
sourceElem.type = "video/mp4";
video1.appendChild(sourceElem);

var video2 = video1.cloneNode(true); //This makes a copy of the element, but makes sure it's not treated as the same element. This means you can add video1 AND this _different_ element to the document. However, unfortunately, everything still needs to get loaded again. I think this is the easiest way to copy an element over, though.
video2.id = "bigVideo";
video1.id = "previewVideo";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    //Now put video1 and video2 where you want.
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is a great solution! I would't have thought of this, i will try this soon. Just a question, where is the `videoElem` from line 8 defined, do you mean `video1` maybe?

Comment: Sorry! Yes, I meant `video1`, not `videoElem`. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: I currently have `place.prepend(video1); $('body').prepend(video2); video1.play(); video2.play();` directly after the `video.id` definition outside of the event listener because I start playing the videos in a custom js-function which is started on user interaction. Unfortunately only the last prepended video (video2 in this case) is added to the site, same if i switch the order of the two prepends. It seems like either jquery or the video element don't support adding nearly the same or the same element twice to one page.   Could you help me at adding the two videos to the page?

Comment: Oh...I guess you need to use the [.cloneNode()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp) method of `video1`. However, that means you need to load `video1` over again, even if you're not writing out the code again.

Comment: i tried using `.cloneNode()`, but as you already said both videos are loaded seperately again. Any other idea?

Comment: Hm...Not really. Sorry I couldn't help you!

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer as well, please take a look at the other answer i just wrote.
I found a solution to display the video twice.

Comment: A variation on this worked for me where I cloned the <video> element already in the HTML and then appended it to the <body>. Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Experimental feature of interest:

```
<video id="vid" src="test.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
<div style="background:-moz-element(#vid); background-size: cover; width: 1280px; height: 720px; "></div>
```

(firefox only and with -moz- prefix as of 2023)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element

https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-images-4/#element-notation

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution can be to add a value to the end of the url with #anything

Since you are loading the video in one video element and want to load it again in a different video element, you can arrange it like below with a **unique** url:

```
<video autoplay id="mainVideo">
    <source src="video.php?videoid=JYpUXXD4xgc&item=1" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

<video autoplay id="previewVideo">
    <source src="video.php?videoid=JYpUXXD4xgc&item=2" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question, it was about telling the browser to "duplicate" or "copy" the rendered video from the first video element instead of letting the browser download both videos.
You can find the solution i wanted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24532111/3582159).

Answer (score -3):

Most Optimal solution

```js
let videoPlayCount = 1;
    let video = document.getElementById('amplify-mould-video');

    video.addEventListener('ended',videoHandler,false);
    function videoHandler() {
        if(videoPlayCount < 2){
            videoPlayCount++;
            video.play();
        }else{
            video.pause();
            video.removeEventListener('ended',videoHandler)
        }
    }
```

```html
<video id="video" muted="" autoplay="" controls>
    <source src="#" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Hello salman, thank you for your answer. As far as i understand this code, this will play one video two times in a row. In contrast, my question here was how to play the same video source in two video elements or other canvas options at the same time - ideally without loading it from the network twice.