# link 4 video element to one source

Tags: javascript, html, video

Help me link one video source to 4  elements. The force src assignation is very CPU expensive as 4 network streams and 4 video encodes produces

```
//very very CPU expensive
video1.src= sameSource
video2.src= sameSource
video3.src= sameSource
video4.src= sameSource
```

Comment: Have your tried video1.src=sameSource; video2.src=video3.src=video4.src=video1.src;

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496605/how-can-i-show-the-same-html-5-video-twice-on-a-website-without-loading-it-twice